# Cloudflare or WAF for blocking wp-loign.php but allowing wp-login.php?foo=bar

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, web-application-firewall

Im new to waf rules and wondering how I would go about blocking `wp-login.php` but allow parameter strings after wp-login.php.

Hopefully via cloudflare rules.

Im using a hide login page plugin and it 403s `wp-login.php`  but allows `wp-login.php?parameters`, but I would also like to waf it so it doesn't eat up my bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not matching `/*wp-login.php*`?

It will match:

- `wp-login.php?parameter` as you wish.
- `//wp-login.php` (I used to see bot using this URL to bypass some weak rules).

Comment: Good suggestion on the // rule.